# MySQL: variable = variable + select statement

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I've got several records in a temp table, and I'd like to take a value from each record and add it to a variable, e.g.

```
color          | caption
--------------------------------
red              stop
blue             state line
yellow           yield
orange           construction
```

var1 = 'red;blue;yellow;orange'

In MSSQL, I could do that this way:

```
-- MSSQL
select var1 = var1 + color
from signShapes
```

In MySQL, that doesn't work. I'd just get "orange."

```
-- mySQL
select var1 = concat(var1, color)
from signShapes
```

No, I know I could accomplish this with a cursor or a loop. I'm curious if I could do this without either, similarly to the MSSQL method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT var1 = GROUP_CONCAT(color SEPARATOR ';')
 FROM signShapes
 GROUP BY color;
```

Comment: In the hopes of one day converting our company's rdbms to MySQL, I'm doing a few personal projects first to get a solid handle on things. I'm learning something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this?

```
select var1 = group_concat(color separator ';')
from signShapes;
```